# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated crashes app

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development, so please pardon my ignorance.

I call a UIViewController from a UIViewController.  The first UIViewController is a list of items, and the second is the detail for each of the items.

ListViewController (first UIViewController):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // initialize a AddViewController
    selItem = indexPath.row;
    selIndexPath = indexPath;
    AddViewController *controller = [[AddViewController alloc] init];
    // give controller the data to display

    // show the AddViewController
    [controller setData:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release]; // release the controller AddViewController
} // end method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

In the 'AddViewController' I have a segment control as both the left and right button bars.  On the left, I have 'Exit' and 'Delete'.  On the right I have 'Add' and 'Save'.  The outlets that the segment controls are linked to are:

AddViewController (second UIViewController):

```
- (IBAction)delExitSegment:sender
{
    // The segmented control was clicked, handle it here 
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:     // Exit Button
            [delegate addViewControllerDidExit:self];
            break;

        case 1:     // Delete Button
            [delegate addViewControllerDelItem:self];
            break;

    }

}

- (IBAction)segmentAction:sender
{
    // The segmented control was clicked, handle it here 
    UISegmentedControl *segCtl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    switch (segCtl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:     // Add Button
            if (currentCell != nil)
                [data setValue:currentCell.textField.text forKey:currentCell.label.text];

            [delegate addViewControllerDidFinishAdding:self];
            break;

        case 1:     // Save Button
            [delegate addViewControllerUpdate:self];
            break;

    }
}
```

When I come back to my first view controller, I have:
ListViewController:

```
- (void)addViewControllerDidFinishAdding:(AddViewController *)controller
{
    NSDictionary *item = [controller values];
    if (item != nil)
    {
        [list addObject:item];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [list writeToFile:itemFilePath atomically:NO];
    [self calcTotal];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)addViewControllerUpdate:(AddViewController *)controller
{
    NSDictionary *item = [controller values];
    if (item != nil)
    {
        [list replaceObjectAtIndex:selItem withObject:item];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [list writeToFile:itemFilePath atomically:NO];
    [self calcTotal];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)addViewControllerDidExit:(AddViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)addViewControllerDelItem:(AddViewController *)controller
{
    NSDictionary *item = [controller values];
    if (item != nil)
    {
        [list removeObjectAtIndex:selItem];
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:selIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [list writeToFile:itemFilePath atomically:NO];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If I exit or delete an item from AddViewController, I have no problems.  When I try and add or save, then my application will crash.  The debugger crashes at dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.  I can't see what's different between the two segment controls.
Any ideas what I may have wrong?

I just discovered that neither the left or right buttons work when I attempt to edit a cell.  The editing cell in AddViewController is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"EditableCell";

    EditableCell *cell = (EditableCell *)[table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[EditableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    NSString *key = [fields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + indexPath.section * 3];
    [cell setLabelText:key];

    cell.textField.text = [data valueForKey:key];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 3))
        cell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
        cell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

    cell.editing = NO;
    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

When you dismiss the view the value of self become unknown, accessing the tableview will definitely crash.

If you want to refresh the tableView just use `[self.tableView reloadData]` and don't dismiss the view.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  If I don't dismiss the model view, the model view does not go away, I need the 'AddViewController' to disappear.

Comment: I have a ListViewController class which uses a table view as a list.  When I select one of the items in the list, then it calls the 'AddViewController' which displays the details of the selected item.  The tableview that is been reloaded is in ListViewController.

Comment: instead of self use the object of ListViewController

Comment: or simply navigate to listviewcontroller using  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; instead of dismissing it.

Comment: I'm a little confused - ListViewController already calls [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; when an item in the list is selected.  It's when I come back to my list.  So I've called a model controller, but when I dismiss it, it crashes.  Have I missed something?

Comment: yes the problem is in self.tableView only. self will point to the AddViewController, but you want to reload the data in ListViewController

Comment: But the code that dismisses the model view is in ListViewController.  Also, when I debug, it doesn't crash on the reload, it crashes when it tries to dismiss the modal view.  When I try and reference ListViewController direct I get compile errors.

Comment: I think the root cause is actually when I start to edit the cells in AddViewController.  If I don't edit any cells, then everything works well.  When I edit a cell, then non of the segment controls work.  I have modified my original post to include the code where a cell is selected for editing in AddViewController.

Comment: Is AddViewController a UITableviewController?

Comment: No - it's UIViewController.  ListViewController is a UITableViewController.

Comment: Does the code work without crash if you comment the [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] line?

Comment: It doesn't really crash, but the model form remains.  I know I need it to return to my main list.

Comment: Try calling [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] in segmentAction: in AddViewController..

Comment: I'll give that a go - I have broken something else at the moment - so I am working through that, and then I'll give your suggestion a go.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter where I dismiss it - that's where it wants to crash.